# Replication SQL Server 2008 to Azure SQL DB login failure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory, transactional-replication

I am trying to setup replication from SQL Server 2008 R2 (publisher and distributor) to Azure SQL database (subscriber). I configured the subscription on the SQL Server 2008 side (push) with a SQL Server User.

In the replication job I see the following error:
2018-10-15 13:53:11.381 Agent message code 20084. The process could not connect to Subscriber ''.

On the subscriber (Azure SQL DB) I see the following in the audit log:

```
additional_information  <login_information><error_code>18456</error_code><error_state>132</error_state></login_information>
database_principal_name (is empty)
succeeded   False
```

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2017) site I understand that error state 132 means AAD error. This is something I don't understand as I am using a SQL Server user.

I am able to connect to the Azure SQL DB from the publisher server using management studio and logging in with the SQL Server account.

Johan

Comment: We had an issue where replication from SQL Server 2012 > SQL Azure would work for a while then it would throw an error 8 (different to yours). We re entered the password in the publisher side and it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring replication between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises, SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported as publisher or distributor as explained on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/replication-to-sql-database) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alberto! I had heard of this before but thought that R2 was supported. Now I know it's not :-(

Comment: I was surprised to see documentation saying otherwise.